# SwiftUI Two Pane Window, List in Each Pane, Selection Highlighting on Second List

Tags: swift, swiftui

In SwiftUI how can I get a two-paned window with a `List` in each pane, and keep selection highlighting in each? My code below is not working, I get the second list, but the list is not selectable. If I add a `NavigationLink` I get the selection highlighting, but obviously I have no legitimate destination view to link to, so I can't use it. I'm kind of at a loss here.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    @Query private var items: [Item]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView {
            List {
                ForEach(items) { item in
                    NavigationLink {
                        Text("Item at \(item.timestamp, format: Date.FormatStyle(date: .numeric, time: .standard))")
                    } label: {
                        Text(item.timestamp, format: Date.FormatStyle(date: .numeric, time: .standard))
                    }
                }
                .onDelete(perform: deleteItems)
            }
#if os(macOS)
            .navigationSplitViewColumnWidth(min: 180, ideal: 200)
#endif
            .toolbar {
#if os(iOS)
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    EditButton()
                }
#endif
                ToolbarItem {
                    Button(action: addItem) {
                        Label("Add Item", systemImage: "plus")
                    }
                }
            }
        } detail: {
            List {
                ForEach(items) { item in
                        Text("Item at \(item.timestamp, format: Date.FormatStyle(date: .numeric, time: .standard))")
                }
                .onDelete(perform: deleteItems)
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To `...get a two-paned window with a List in each pane, and keep selection highlighting in each`, you could try this approach, using a `selectedItem` that
determines which item is currently selected. Then color
the background accordingly.

Example code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    @Query private var items: [Item]

    @State private var selectedItem: Item? // <--- here
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView {
            List {
                ForEach(items) { item in
                    Text(item.timestamp, format: Date.FormatStyle(date: .numeric, time: .standard))
                        .onTapGesture {
                            selectedItem = item  // <--- here
                        }
                        .background(selectedItem == item ? .red : .clear) // <--- here
                }
                .onDelete(perform: deleteItems)
            }
#if os(macOS)
            .navigationSplitViewColumnWidth(min: 180, ideal: 200)
#endif
            .toolbar {
#if os(iOS)
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    EditButton()
                }
#endif
                ToolbarItem {
                    Button(action: addItem) {
                        Label("Add Item", systemImage: "plus")
                    }
                }
            }
        } detail: {
            List {
                ForEach(items) { item in
                    Text("Item at \(item.timestamp, format: Date.FormatStyle(date: .numeric, time: .standard))")
                        .background(selectedItem == item ? .red : .clear) // <--- here
                        .onTapGesture {
                            selectedItem = item  // <--- here
                        }
                }
                .onDelete(perform: deleteItems)
            }
        }
    }

    private func addItem() {
        withAnimation {
            let newItem = Item(timestamp: Date())
            modelContext.insert(newItem)
        }
    }

    private func deleteItems(offsets: IndexSet) {
        withAnimation {
            for index in offsets {
                modelContext.delete(items[index])
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

EDIT-1:

if you want independent selection for the `Lists`, then use this approach:

EDIT-2

with double tap and change in foreground color.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    @Query private var items: [Item]

    @State private var sideItem: Item?    // <--- here
    @State private var detailsItem: Item? // <--- here
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView {
            List {
                ForEach(items) { item in
                    Text(item.timestamp, format: Date.FormatStyle(date: .numeric, time: .standard))
                        .onTapGesture {
                            sideItem = item  // <--- here
                        }
                       .simultaneousGesture(TapGesture(count: 2).onEnded { // <--- here
                        print("------> double tap")
                       })
                       .background(sideItem == item ? .blue : .clear) // <--- here
                       .foregroundStyle(sideItem == item ? .white : .black) // <--- here
                }
                .onDelete(perform: deleteItems)
            }
#if os(macOS)
            .navigationSplitViewColumnWidth(min: 180, ideal: 200)
#endif
            .toolbar {
#if os(iOS)
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    EditButton()
                }
#endif
                ToolbarItem {
                    Button(action: addItem) {
                        Label("Add Item", systemImage: "plus")
                    }
                }
            }
        } detail: {
            List {
                ForEach(items) { item in
                    Text("Item at \(item.timestamp, format: Date.FormatStyle(date: .numeric, time: .standard))")
                        .onTapGesture {
                            detailsItem = item  // <--- here
                        }
                        .simultaneousGesture(TapGesture(count: 2).onEnded {
                        print("------> double tap")
                        })
                       .background(detailsItem == item ? .blue : .clear) // <--- here
                       .foregroundStyle(detailsItem == item ? .white : .black) // <--- here
                }
                .onDelete(perform: deleteItems)
            }
        }
    }

    private func addItem() {
        withAnimation {
            let newItem = Item(timestamp: Date())
            modelContext.insert(newItem)
        }
    }

    private func deleteItems(offsets: IndexSet) {
        withAnimation {
            for index in offsets {
                modelContext.delete(items[index])
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: I see what you are saying, and it *kind* of works, but it's janky. It does set the background highlight, but the text doesn't change from black to white and double-click and return actions are ignored. Starting to seem like SwiftUI was not intended at all for what I'm trying to do here. I might wind up having to load an NSView on the Mac and UIView on iOS to get the appropriate behavior.

Comment: You can easily add 2 lines of code to cater for the double tap and the change in the
 text color. Updated my answer with these extra features.